# OutOfMemory Exception duing mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a slave MySQL server to an existing server. I ran the following mysqldump on the master to prepare the data for the slave initially.

```
mysqldump.exe -u ... -p... --single-transaction --flush-logs --skip-lock-tables --master-data=2 > all-dbs.sql
```

But after a while, it gave the following error;

```
Program 'mysqldump.exe' failed to run: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.At line:1 char:1
+ .\mysqldump.exe -u ... -p... --skip-lock-tables --single-tran ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\mysqldump.exe -u ... -p... --skip-lock-tables --single-tran ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

The master MySQL server has 3.5GB memory, and the data is about 5GB.
It is running MySQL 5.7.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: depending from what memory You have free (not cached and not used by mysql) it could be variants, but why not make a dump from slave? mysqldump -u -p --host=master_ip

Comment: What are you using to actually spawn the `mysqldump` command?  Obviously you are not simply typing it at a shell prompt.  One thought is that you need the `--opt` option, which should be enabled by default but might be disabled in local config.  This option implies the poorly-named `--quick` option, which reduces memory consumption while creating a dump, and might also be disabled, so adding `--quick` might also be helpful.

Comment: Please show us your `my.cnf` -- it sounds like something is set too high.

Comment: The server is Azure VM - 2 core with 3.5 GB.  I used windows powershell to run the mysqldump command.  After creating 4+GB output file, I received the error message.  Since I was in a hurry, I changed the VM's config to 4-core and 7GB, and was successfully run the mysqldump.  However, I was not able to import the file into the slave server. It complained that there are binary characters in the line 1.   I ran mysqldump again on the master, but used windows cmd.exe (not powershell).  This worked fine with no error, and also the output was only 2.5 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Just like  [Michael - sqlbot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/11651/michael-sqlbot) suggested, --quick would help. Official MySQL Doc states:

> *--quick, -q*
>
> This option is useful for dumping large tables. It forces mysqldump to
>   retrieve rows for a table from the server a row at a time rather than
>   retrieving the entire row set and buffering it in memory before
>   writing it out.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_quick

Regarding the PowerShell issue, there's a note on MySQL Doc:

> Note:
>
> A dump made using PowerShell on Windows with output redirection
>   creates a file that has UTF-16 encoding:
>
> `shell> mysqldump [options] > dump.sql`
>
> However, UTF-16 is not permitted
>   as a connection character set (see Section 11.1.4, “Connection
>   Character Sets and Collations”), so the dump file will not load
>   correctly. To work around this issue, use the --result-file option,
>   which creates the output in ASCII format:
>
> ```
> shell> mysqldump [options] --result-file=dump.sql
> ```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html